# Laravel 3 - 404 event listener not being picked up from controllers

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-3

I'm trying to use the default event listener in Laravel for errors (i.e. 404).

I have the following code:

```
Event::listen('404', function()
{
    return Controller::call('errors@404');
});
```

This works fine (it calls the error controller's 404 action) if the URL doesn't exist (i.e. doesn't hit a controller).  But when the path hits a controller, then it seems to ignore that event listener.

Do I need to do something to tell it to use that listener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a catch-all route - like:

```
Route::controller(Controller::detect())
```

Then you are correct - the event does not seem to be captured by the Events class. It might be a bug - I'm not sure.

However for 404 it is a really easy fix - just change your base_controller:

```
public function __call($method, $parameters)
{
    return Response::error('404');
}
```

to

```
public function __call($method, $parameters)
{
    Event::fire('404');
}
```

and it works as expected

Comment: (i.e. `return Response::error('404');`) That's how I'm raising it in my base controller and it doesn't seem to be capturing it.

Comment: I've changed my answer - try that

Comment: That works for a 404, but I'll need to Event::fire('405') for forbiddens as well?  That seems kind of clunky / wrong ...

Comment: I agree Judda - its probably a bug in Laravel 3. But if you put a small amount of logic in your base_controller to handle it - you'll fix it immediately.

Comment: Thanks for the help :)  I'll do as you suggest ... it's weird if I do that, it randomly echos "Array".

Comment: Figured out why there was the Array showing up.  You need to remove the `return` from the `__call` method.